# bash scripting - how to effectively iterate a key-value pair list in a text file to load a variable

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, for-loop

What's the best way to iterate this list? (key separated by ":" value and separated by new line)

I have a file that has these values in a text file:

```
cl1:AbC!123
cl2:EfF{3201p
cl3:Zrq12@1q5t
```

Its basically: `key:value`

I have a function that needs to be executed (one at a time)
for each `key:value` in the list

Where:

```
key=clnmbr
value=pw
```

Function:

```
myfunction()
  {
   mycount=$(PGPASSWORD=${pw} psql -h myhost-1-${clnmbr}.com -U masteruser -d dev -p 5439 -t -c "select count(datname) from pg_database;")
}
```

So basically I want to loop through each line in my list and execute my function. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: BTW, I'm almost certain you're describing what's what backwards. You say it's `key:value` and `key=pw`, but the key is something like `cl1` or `cl2` -- not a good password -- and the value looks much more password-y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while IFS=: read -r clnmbr pw; do
  myfunction
done
```

Comment: ok, sorta understand, but how do I read it in as a file? would something like this work? `while IFS=: read -r  < "myfile.lst"`?

Comment: You'd want to put `< "myfile.lst"` after the `done`, to redirect for the list as a whole -- if you put it after the `read`, it'll just reread the first line over and over.

Comment: got it. it works. thanks!